# How can Chrome extension background script communicate with web page service worker?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker

Our webapp registers a service worker. We also have a Chrome extension. What we need is to send messages from service worker to the extension without having the webapp open. What is the right approach to do that?

Our current solution is requesting some URL in the service worker and capturing it in the extension's background script using `webRequest` - `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener`. It works but it looks pretty much nonstandardly.

Comment: Alas, not yet: https://crbug.com/452942 and https://crbug.com/545535

Comment: Martin, I need to do the same. Could you post some example code of your solution?

Comment: @MichaelUpdike https://gist.github.com/zdila/ba6c0c1e0be5caafbc1d5bb4832f7d75

Comment: Hi, is there any new solution? I would like to send data from firebase-messaging-sw.js to manifest v3 service worker in order to set badge text. Normal service worker don't have set badge text API available.

Comment: Any update on this?  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=452942 is closed without any resolution.

Answer (score 2):

(from wOxxOm's comment, since he hates answering anywhere but in comments)

Your solution is as good as any - before more straightforward support is added, as per [this feature request](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=452942).