# Sound does not work in service worker in Chrome desktop push notification

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, push-notification, service-worker

I'm trying to play sound in push notification in Chrome browser when I get notification.
And I have already set the browser push notification on my site but it does not play sound. I'm already going through the option for sound but get no sound.

```js
option = {
     'body' : 'This is tst Description',
     'icon' : 'icon.png',
     'silent' : 'false',
     'sound' : 'bell.mp3'
}
```

If there is any other way to play the sound in the notification, please let me know.

Comment: Yes browser doesnt support sound notification.

Comment: If you know when to play sound, you can manually play it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105063/how-to-play-a-notification-sound-on-websites.

Answer (score 5):

or you can declare myAudio object globally and use play() funcation after or before notification is popped.

```
myAudio = new Audio("alert_tone.mp3");

var notification = new Notification("Hi there", options);
myAudio.play();
```

Comment: This will play the audio when loading the page - but not when a notification is sent.

Answer (score 4):

Currently browsers doesn't support Notification.sound
see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification

Comment: But why it has a property named "silent"?And the docs say "Specifies whether the notification should be silent — i.e., no sounds or vibrations should be issued, regardless of the device settings."

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use the *chrome* `web-extension`  [background_pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages).

It will listen to the `service worker` and play the *audio*
The simple method for it would be to *requesting the URL in the service worker and capture it in the background script using the `chrome.webRequest`* as mentioned in the [link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    callback, filter, opt_extraInfoSpec);
```

as mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663229/how-can-chrome-extension-background-script-communicate-with-web-page-service-wor)

**Update**
As mentioned in this [link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/3868550081d275ef8f73933ffcec88da453215a2)

> Service Workers require a secure origin, such as HTTPS.  *chrome-extension:// pages are not HTTP/HTTPS*, but are secure so this change becomes a necessary step to allow extensions to register a Service Worker.
>
> **"chrome-extension"** is added as a scheme allowing service workers.

In the `serviceworker script`

*First you need to register your extension in the [manifest.json](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest)*

- Request the url in the service worker
- Capture it in background script using the `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener`
- Play the sound in `background.js`

*and as mentioned by @Alexander currently there is no support for the sound in the MDN*

Comment: Thanks For your ans but Background Page Not work in ServiceWorker

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in link bellow

At the time of writing, no browser has support for this option.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/display-a-notification#sound

[image]